# Serial Port DataReceived firing multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm developing a winforms app that talks to a FPGA device. Since the device is still in development, I'm trying to simulate it using com0com (http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) and another winforms app as the simulator.

I'm sending a byte array of 44 bytes from my app to the simulator:

CC AA 01 28 09 2A 0C 00 01 FF 00 FA 02 FF 01 5E 03 FF 01 C2 04 FF 02 26 05 FF 02 8A 06 FF 02 EE 07 FF 03 52 08 FF 03 B6 09 FF 04 1A

The first 4 bytes are the header and the fourth byte contains the number of bytes to follow. In this case 40=0x28. There is no termination value in the API spec. Here is how I'm handling the DataRecieved event:

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int byte_count = 0;
    int read_count = 0;
    while (comPort.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        byte_count = comPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] byteTemp = new byte[byte_count];
        read_count = comPort.Read(byteTemp, 0, byte_count);
    }
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[read_count];
    int intNumBytes2read = byteBuffer[3];

    // do other stuff
}
```

My problem is that the simulator does not always receive the entire payload when the event fires. In fact, the event usually fires more than once each time I send data from my app to the simulator.  My research on the subject indicates that this is a common problem and that I need to create some sort of queuing mechanism.  With my limited C# experience, I'm struggling with the understanding of how to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a state machine to keep track of how far you've progressed in the reception of a message.  That can look like this:

```
private int state;
private byte[] payload;
private int payloadIndex;

private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    while (comPort.BytesToRead > 0) {
        byte b = (byte)comPort.BaseStream.ReadByte();
        switch (state) {
            case 0: 
                if (b == 0xcc) state++;
                else protocolViolation("Bad header, expected 0xcc");
                break;
            case 1:
                if (b == 0xaa) state++;
                else protocolViolation("Bad header, expected 0xaa");
                break;
            case 2:
                if (b == 0x01) state++;
                else protocolViolation("Bad header, expected 0x01");
                break;
            case 3:
                payload = new byte[b];
                payloadIndex = 0;
                state++;
                break;
            case 4:
                payload[payloadIndex++] = b;
                if (payloadIndex == payload.Length) {
                    processPayload(payload);
                    state = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void protocolViolation(string why) {
    state = 0;
    Debug.WriteLine(why);
}

private void processPayload(byte[] payload) {
    // etc..
}
```